# Pandas: add date field to parsed timestamp

Tags: pandas

I have several date specific text files (for ex 20150211.txt) that looks like

```
TopOfBook       0x21    60      07:15:00.862    101     85      5       109     500     24      +
TopOfBook       0x21    60      07:15:00.882    101     91      400     109     500     18      +
TopOfBook       0x21    60      07:15:00.890    101     91      400     105     80      14      +
TopOfBook       0x21    60      07:15:00.914    101     93.3    400     105     80      11.7    +
```

where the 4th column contains the timestamp.

If I read this into pandas with automatic parsing

```
df_top = pd.read_csv('TOP_20150210.txt', sep='\t', names=hdr_top, parse_dates=[3])
```

I get:

```
0   TopOfBook   0x21    60  2015-05-17 07:15:00.862000  101 85.0    5   109.0   500 24.0    +
1   TopOfBook   0x21    60  2015-05-17 07:15:00.882000  101 91.0    400 109.0   500 18.0    +
2   TopOfBook   0x21    60  2015-05-17 07:15:00.890000  101 91.0    400 105.0   80  14.0    +
```

Where the time part of course is correct, but how do I add the correct date part of this timestamp (2015-02-11)? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `apply` and construct the datetime using your desired date values and then copying the time portion to the constructor:

```
In [9]:
import datetime as dt
df[3] = df[3].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(2015,2,11,x.hour,x.minute,x.second,x.microsecond))
df
Out[9]:
          0     1   2                          3    4     5    6    7    8   \
0  TopOfBook  0x21  60 2015-02-11 07:15:00.862000  101  85.0    5  109  500   
1  TopOfBook  0x21  60 2015-02-11 07:15:00.882000  101  91.0  400  109  500   
2  TopOfBook  0x21  60 2015-02-11 07:15:00.890000  101  91.0  400  105   80   
3  TopOfBook  0x21  60 2015-02-11 07:15:00.914000  101  93.3  400  105   80   

     9  10  
0  24.0  +  
1  18.0  +  
2  14.0  +  
3  11.7  +
```

Answer (score 2):

After parsing the dates, the third column has dtype `<M8[ns]`. This is the NumPy datetime64 dtype with nanosecond resolution. You can do fast date arithmetic by [adding or subtracting NumPy timedelta64s](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

So, for example, subtracting 6 days from `df[3]` yields

```
In [139]: df[3] - np.array([6], dtype='<m8[D]')
Out[139]: 
0   2015-05-11 07:15:00.862000
1   2015-05-11 07:15:00.882000
2   2015-05-11 07:15:00.890000
3   2015-05-11 07:15:00.914000
Name: 3, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

To find the correct number of days to subtract you could use

```
today = df.iloc[0,3]
date = pd.Timestamp(re.search(r'\d+', filename).group())
n = (today-date).days
```

---

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

filename = '20150211.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None, parse_dates=[3])
today = df.iloc[0,3]
date = pd.Timestamp(re.search(r'\d+', filename).group())
n = (today-date).days
df[3] -= np.array([n], dtype='<m8[D]')
print(df)
```

yields

```
           0     1   2                          3    4     5    6    7    8  \
0  TopOfBook  0x21  60 2015-02-11 07:15:00.862000  101  85.0    5  109  500   
1  TopOfBook  0x21  60 2015-02-11 07:15:00.882000  101  91.0  400  109  500   
2  TopOfBook  0x21  60 2015-02-11 07:15:00.890000  101  91.0  400  105   80   
3  TopOfBook  0x21  60 2015-02-11 07:15:00.914000  101  93.3  400  105   80   

      9  
0  24.0  
1  18.0  
2  14.0  
3  11.7
```